# Изображение залезло на border

Tags: html, css

Всем привет имею изображение. Сделал его ширину и высоту в процентах,

```
max-width: 100%;
```

чтобы при уменьшении, оно уменьшалось. Проблема в том, что она находится в блоке, где есть border и следовательно, она есть и вокруг картинки. Как можно сделать, чтобы оно залезло на border. Если задать фиксированную высоту и ширину, то оно залезит на border, но тогда при уменьшении не будет уменьшаться.

Answer (score 0):

через width:calc(100% + 2px);
margin: 0 1px;

Answer (score 0):

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}

.border,
.no__border {
  display: block;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 4px solid red;
}

.no__border img {
  width: calc(100% + 8px);
  margin-top: -4px;
  margin-left: -4px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
Было
<div class="border"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/421748346907152384/RBkX2wzZ_400x400.jpeg"></div>
Стало
<div class="no__border"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/421748346907152384/RBkX2wzZ_400x400.jpeg"></div>
```